# How to access height and width properties of fotorama active frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I need to resize the current image in active frame when a button is clicked but I can't access the image properties. I don't want to change the fotorama size just the current image.

Here is my code

```
function zoomIn() {
     try {
      var $fotoramaDiv = $('#fotorama').fotorama();
         var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
         var $frame = fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame;
        //the following line does not work
         $frame.childNode.height=500;
     }
     catch (error) {
        alert(error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding another class or property (e.g. active) to your active image and try to call $frame.find(".active").height(yourHeight).

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick attr in img element with code onclick=zoomIn(); and then set the JQuery code as following:

```
unction zoomIn() {
        try {           

          $('#fotorama').css({"width":"250px","height":"250px"});
        }
        catch (error) {
           alert(error.Message);
       }
   }
```